# Improving binary recursion calculation

Tags: computability

I am trying to write a program in Python for the infamous egg drop puzzle using recursion. In case you do not know the problem statement, here it is:

https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/dashboard?c=32003#s=p2

One solution to this puzzle would be to use a recursive function that returns the maximum floors of a building that would be allow for $Solvable(F, D, B)$ to be true, represented as such, as function $f$:

$f(D, B)$ $=$ $1$ $+$ $f(D - 1, $ $B - 1)$ $+$ $f(D - 1$, $B)$

... where $D$ is the number of drops left, and $B$ is the number of breaks allowed. This solution makes use of how an egg can either break on $f(D - 1, $ $B - 1)$ floors below, and $f(D - 1$, $B)$ floors above.

As you can see, this results in the formation of a binary recursive function as shown above. Combined with the fact that we know that $f(1, B)$ $=$ $1$ for all values of $B$, and how $f(D, 1)$ $=$ $D$ for all values of $D$, this problem should be no problem to solve for a program that can handle recursion very well. However, Python has a knack for being unable to handle recursion as well as some other languages.

As such I would like to know whether the maximum floors returned by function $f$ can be determined for a set of values where $1<=D, B<=200,000,000$ in Python.

> Here is a list of the techniques I have tried so far, to little avail:
>   1. Memoisation (Caching values of $f(D, B)$)
>   2. Since we know that $f(d, b)$ for $d <= b$ is equal to $f(d, b)$ where $d = b$, with $d$ held constant, we can reduce the number of cached pairs of $d$ and $b$
>   3. When $d = b$, $f(d, b)$ is equivalent to $2^d - 1$, thus removing the need for the binary recursion for $d = b$

Comment: This question seems a little off-topic. 
First: we don't discuss implementations in specific programming languages here.
Second: if you really only want to know is it possible, then the answer is yes (assuming you have an unreasonable amount of memory and lots of time, e.g. a few years). I'm guessing that you actually want to know how to solve the GCJ problem, and solving that might not require to compute the function f for all values (hint).

Comment: @Jakube Alright, thanks for your comment, I'll try to solve it without computation of all values beforehand... I am currently looking into another solution that just might work.

Comment: PS in the future, please include at least a summary of the problem statement with the link. Links die. Questions should be as self-contained as possible

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes, will do so in the future, thanks for the feedback!